# Access user info from lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'm working on a serverless app with aws.

I use AWS Cognito User Pool to manage user : register, login, logout.
Once those users have been confirmed, I use AWS Cognito Identity Pool to get temporary credentials. Then I use those credentials to access the api (the endpoint on my api require AWS_IAM for Auth and call lambda).

All of that work perfectly. But I need to know which user has requested the action. In the lambda I can get the IdentityId from my Identity Pool. But I need to get attributes from my user in User Pool.

So my question is : is there a way to get a user from User Pool using the IdentityId of the Identity attached to it ? Or at least, get the access token ? I know I can send the access token in headers but I would like to only depend on the AWS_IAM auth.

Answer (score 0):

Getting from a federated `identity_id` back to the user pool user is tricky because there's no guarantee it *is* a user pool user (it could well be someone from Facebook, or even an unauthenticated user- depending on your configuration).

1. Given an `IdentityId` you can use [identity:GetOpenIdToken](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetOpenIdToken.html) to get a valid OpenId token (you can ignore the `logins` part of the request if you *are* just using UserPools).
2. You can then use this token against the [userpools:GetUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_GetUser.html) end point.

There's a few pitfalls here, like ensuring you authenticate with a scope that allows you to see all the attributes you care about. If you haven't, then you'll need to use the `username` returned with [userpools:AdminGetUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminGetUser.html) to get the full user profile.

Comment: But sub attribute of a user in User Pool is not equal to identity_id of the identity in Identity Pool

Comment: Sorry- I had misunderstood and thought you had an idToken- I've updated my answer for the approach you'd take with identity_id